# Create an array with multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple checkboxes where the user should check the series he watches. In my database i want to update the column "watch" with the value "yes" in every series he checked (i have already created a column with all the series in it).

The HTML code:

```
<p>Please check the series you watch:</p>
<form action="2.php" method="post">
Game Of Thrones <input type="checkbox" value="Game Of Thrones" name="series"/><br>
The Big Bang Theory <input type="checkbox" value="The Big Bang Theory" name="series"/><br>
Arrow <input type="checkbox" value="Arrow" name="series"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The send.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$series = $_POST['series'];
$sql = "UPDATE data SET watch='yes' WHERE series='$series'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

It works as long as the user check only one series, but when he check two or more it updates only one of the series he checked.

Help?

Comment: you need to treat the same checkbox group as an array in your form. Use brackets and use a foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML code like:

```
<p>Please check the series you watch:</p>
<form action="2.php" method="post">
  <!-- make the name as an array -->
    Game Of Thrones <input type="checkbox" value="Game Of Thrones" name="series[]"/><br>
    The Big Bang Theory <input type="checkbox" value="The Big Bang Theory" name="series[]"/><br>
    Arrow <input type="checkbox" value="Arrow" name="series[]"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And your **send.php** :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$series = $_POST['series'];
for( $i = 0; $i < count($series); $i ++) {

  $sql = "UPDATE data SET watch='yes' WHERE series='$series[$i]'";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "Record updated successfully";
  }  
  else {
     echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
  }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to POST it as array, simple example:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="fields[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="fields[]" value="2" />
</form>
```

After it was POSTed, you have an array `$_POST['fields']` with all checked checkbox values. Process it like this:

```
foreach($_POST['fields'] as $field)
    $db->query("UPDATE table SET value = 1 WHERE id = '" . $db->real_escape_string($field) . "'");
```

Comment: `intval` won't work, since OP has strings for their values.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: This is only an example. But I can change it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Set the input names as:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Game Of Thrones" name="series[]"/>
```

That way `$_POST['series']` will be an array.

If you are updating multiple rows in database build the query string like this:

```
$series = array_map( function( $item ) use ( $conn ) {
    return $conn->real_escape_string( $item );
}, $_POST['series'] );

$query = "UPDATE data SET watch='yes' WHERE series IN ( '" . implode( "', '", $series ) . "' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the checkboxes as array in your form:

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Game Of Thrones" name="series[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="The Big Bang Theory" name="series[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Arrow" name="series[]"/>
```

### PHP

```
var_dump($_POST['series']);
```

See the [PHP reference on this topic](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Be aware that your code contains an **SQL injection vulnerability**! [See how to protect your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Best is to use PHP's [PDO (PHP Data Objects) extension](http://www.php.net/pdo).